# Error 1004 when trying to run a macro to highlight cells based on condition

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet that has all of the column headers in row 1. Cell B2 contains a date. I then have 25 month columns after (K2 to AH2) the column headers in rows K1 to AH1 are the months, starting with the current month. I'm trying to highlight all of the cells from K2 to AH2 only if their column header date is less then the value in B2.

So for instance, B2 is 13-June-14. K1 is a formula to get today's month. so the formula is Today() with the cell formatted to `MMM-YY` (FEB-14).

I thought it'd be pretty easy as I'm just comparing 2 dates and highlighting a different cell if one is less then the other. I'm guessing I'm getting an error due to not converting the B2 date to month format? Here's the error I receive.

```
Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.
```

Here's my code:

```
Sub Highlight()


Dim firstColumn As Integer
Dim lastColumn As Integer
Dim firstRow As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim rowCounter As Integer
Dim columnCounter As Integer


firstColumn = 9
firstRow = 2
lastColumn = 32
lastRow = 6
columnCounter = firstColumn

Do Until columnCounter = lastColumn
    If Cells(K, 1).Value < Cells(B, 2).Value Then
    Cells(columnCounter, lastRow).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If

    columnCounter = columnCounter + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Jut highlight K2:AH2 and goto conditinoal formating, Formula, and use a formula to say values < $B$2

Answer (score 2):

you error is most likely occuring due to this line of code

```
If Cells(K, 1).Value < Cells(B, 2).Value Then
```

If you're using Cells then you need to specify the numeric row and col (in that order), ie Cells(1, 2) refers to row 1 col 2 or B1. What is K and B? are they variables because they aren't declared or initialised in the code you provided. Therefore it's trying to find cell at row 0, which doesn't exist.

If you want to specify the alpha numeric location of a cell, use `Range("K1")` or `Cells(1, "K")` bearing in mind that the row goes first

Furthermore there's a couple of other issues with your code that won't do what you want it to do.

1. If Cells(K, 1).Value < Cells(B, 2).Value Then

Even if you fix the cell reference K1 and B2, every iteration of your loop is comparing K1 and B2.

1. Cells(columnCounter, lastRow).Interior.Color = vbYellow

Again the parameters that go in here have to be row first then column. Also, the variable lastRow never changes, you've assigned it to 6 and it will be 6 for every iteration of the loop

For what you are doing at the least you will need 2 nested loops to go through rows and columns! I've written some sample code for you to guide you. let me know if you need more help

```
Sub Highlight()

Dim firstColumn As Integer
Dim lastColumn As Integer
Dim firstRow As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim rowCounter As Integer
Dim columnCounter As Integer

firstColumn = 9
firstRow = 2
lastColumn = 32
lastRow = 6

For columnCounter = firstColumn To lastColumn
    For rowCounter = firstRow To lastRow
        If Cells(1, columnCounter) < Cells(rowCounter, "B") Then
            Cells(rowCounter, columnCounter).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End If
    Next rowCounter
Next columnCounter

End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 Nicely explained.